# Is the space $(X,d)$ complete? If not what is its completion?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Is the space $(X,d)$ complete? If not what is its completion?

a) X is the set of all continuous on [0,1] functions, $$d(x, y) = \sup_{0 \le t\le1}\ t^2 |x(t) - y(t)|$$

b) $X = \{x\in C[0,1]: \sup_{0 \le t\le1}\ t^{-2} |x(t)| < \infty\}$, $d(x,y) = \sup_{0 \le t\le1}|x(t) - y(t)|$

For the solution of part a I came up with:
Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence and let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Then $\exists P \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon\ \forall n,m\ge P$$ 
$$\sup_{0 \le t\le1}\ t^2 |x_n(t) - x_m(t)|< \epsilon\ \forall n,m\ge P$$ 
Then,
$\sup_{0 \le t\le1}\ t^2 |x_n(t) - x_m(t)| \le \sup_{0 \le t\le1}\ |x_n(t) - x_m(t)|$

But then I do not know what to do next I do not know if such an approach is true:
r > 0 be arbitrary,
$ \sup_{0 \le t\le1}\ |x_n(t) - x_m(t)| < r $

thus metric space is complete.

Also for the solution of part b I thought I would follow almost same steps but cannot find a Cauchy sequence that shows it is not complete.

Comment: The idea for (a) is that the metric "ignores" what's going on at $t = 0$. So if you have a function $y(t)$ that is close to the function $$ x(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & t = 0 \\ 0 & t \ne 0 \end{cases} $$ then $d(x,y) \approx 0$.

Comment: Hint: (a) is incomplete, and you need to find a Cauchy sequence that does not converge, as Trevor Gunn indicates. For (b) The map $$C[0,1] \to X : f(t) \mapsto t^2f(t)$$ is a homeomorphism.